# How to get all array edges?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a n x n array, and want to receive its outline values. For example,

**[4,5,6,7]**

**[2**,2,6,**3]**

**[4**,4,9,**4]**

**[8,1,6,1]**

from this, i would get this

```
[4,5,6,7,3,4,1,6,1,8,4,2]
```

(see where bold)

So essentially, what is the most **efficient** way of getting a 1D array of all the values going around the edges of a 2D array?
I ask because I assume there is a numPy function that helps with this (which I haven't yet found!), instead of doing it manually with loops?

Comment: Does the order matters?

Comment: No, luckily not in my case :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [1]: arr=np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
In [2]: arr
Out[2]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

A relatively straight forward way of doing this - in clockwise order is:

```
In [5]: alist=[arr[0,:-1], arr[:-1,-1], arr[-1,::-1], arr[-2:0:-1,0]]
In [6]: alist
Out[6]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([ 3,  7, 11]), array([15, 14, 13, 12]), array([8, 4])]
In [7]: np.concatenate(alist)
Out[7]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  7, 11, 15, 14, 13, 12,  8,  4])
```

In a sense it's a loop, in that I have to build 4 slices.  But if 4 is small compared to `n`, that's a small price.  It has to concatenate at some level.

If order doesn't matter we could simplify the slices some (e.g. forgetting the reverse order, etc).

```
alist=[arr[0,:], arr[1:,-1], arr[-1,:-1], arr[1:-1,0]]
```

If I didn't care about order, or double counting the corners I could use:

```
np.array([arr[[0,n],:], arr[:,[0,n]].T]).ravel()
```

eliminating the duplicate corners

```
In [18]: np.concatenate((arr[[0,n],:].ravel(), arr[1:-1,[0,n]].ravel()))
Out[18]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3, 12, 13, 14, 15,  4,  7,  8, 11])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one vectorized approach to create a mask of such edge pixels/elements and then simply indexing into the array to get those -

```
def border_elems(a, W): # Input array : a, Edgewidth : W
    n = a.shape[0]
    r = np.minimum(np.arange(n)[::-1], np.arange(n))
    return a[np.minimum(r[:,None],r)<W]
```

Again, this not exactly meant for performance, but more for cases when you might to vary the edge-width or just create such a mask of such edge elements. The mask would be : `np.minimum(r[:,None],r)<W` as created at the last step.

Sample run -

```
In [89]: a
Out[89]: 
array([[49, 49, 12, 90, 42],
       [91, 58, 92, 16, 78],
       [97, 19, 58, 84, 84],
       [86, 31, 80, 78, 69],
       [29, 95, 38, 51, 92]])

In [90]: border_elems(a,1)
Out[90]: array([49, 49, 12, 90, 42, 91, 78, 97, 84, 86, 69, 29, 95, 38, 51, 92])

In [91]: border_elems(a,2) # Note this will select all but the center one : 58
Out[91]: 
array([49, 49, 12, 90, 42, 91, 58, 92, 16, 78, 97, 19, 84, 84, 86, 31, 80,
       78, 69, 29, 95, 38, 51, 92])
```

For generic shape, we can extend like so -

```
def border_elems_generic(a, W): # Input array : a, Edgewidth : W
    n1 = a.shape[0]
    r1 = np.minimum(np.arange(n1)[::-1], np.arange(n1))
    n2 = a.shape[1]
    r2 = np.minimum(np.arange(n2)[::-1], np.arange(n2))
    return a[np.minimum(r1[:,None],r2)<W]
```

**`2D convolution` based solution for generic shape**

Here's another with `2D convolution` that takes care of generic 2D shape -

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

k = np.ones((3,3),dtype=int) # kernel
boundary_elements = a[convolve2d(np.ones(a.shape,dtype=int),k,'same')<9]
```

Sample run -

```
In [36]: a
Out[36]: 
array([[4, 3, 8, 3, 1],
       [1, 5, 6, 6, 7],
       [9, 5, 2, 5, 9],
       [2, 2, 8, 4, 7]])

In [38]: k = np.ones((3,3),dtype=int)

In [39]: a[convolve2d(np.ones(a.shape,dtype=int),k,'same')<9]
Out[39]: array([4, 3, 8, 3, 1, 1, 7, 9, 9, 2, 2, 8, 4, 7])
```

Comment: This approach only works on arrays with dimensions of equal length. Testing on `a = np.ones(10,11)` fails, for instance.

Comment: @TomNorway Added an alternative one for generic shape.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list is in the following format:

```
l = [
     [4, 5, 6, 7],
     [2, 2, 6, 3],
     [4, 4, 9, 4],
     [8, 1, 6, 1]
    ]
```

You can achieve what you want with this quick one-liner, using list comprehensions:

```
out = list(l[0]) +  # [4, 5, 6, 7]
      list([i[-1] for i in l[1:-1]]) +  # [3, 4]
      list(reversed(l[-1])) +  # [1, 6, 1, 8]
      list(reversed([i[0] for i in l[1:-1]])) # [4, 2]

print(out)  # gives [4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 1, 6, 1, 8, 4, 2]
```

This works whether you have a plain python list or a numpy array.

Regarding efficiency, using `%timeit` on a 20000x20000 matrix, this method took `16.4ms`.

```
l = np.random.random(20000, 20000)
%timeit list(l[0]) + list(...) + list(...) + list(...)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.4 ms per loop
```

I'm sure there are more efficient methods to accomplish this task, but I think that's pretty good for a one-liner solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `itertools.groupby` and `list comprehension` like the example below:

```
a = [
        [4,5,6,7],
        [2,2,6,3],
        [4,4,9,4],
        [8,1,6,1],
    ]

from itertools import groupby

def edges(a = list):
    final, i = [], []
    for k, _ in groupby(a[1:-1], lambda x : [x[0], x[-1]]):
        i += k

    return a[0] + [k for n in range(1,len(i), 2) for k in i[n:n+1]] + a[-1][::-1] + [k for n in range(0, len(i), 2) for k in i[n:n+1] ][::-1]
```

Output:

```
print(edges(a))
>>> [4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 1, 6, 1, 8, 4, 2]
```

Test using `timeit`:

```
a = [
        [4,5,6,7],
        [2,2,6,3],
        [4,4,9,4],
        [8,1,6,1],
    ]

from itertools import groupby

def edges():
    final, i = [], []
    for k, _ in groupby(a[1:-1], lambda x : [x[0], x[-1]]):
        i += k

    return a[0] + [k for n in range(1,len(i), 2) for k in i[n:n+1]] + a[-1][::-1] + [k for n in range(0, len(i), 2) for k in i[n:n+1] ][::-1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("edges()", setup="from __main__ import edges", number = 100))
```

Best time was `0.0006266489999688929`

Answer (score 1):

It's probably slower than the alternatives mentioned in the other answers because it's creating a mask (which was my use-case then) it can be used in your case:

```
def mask_borders(arr, num=1):
    mask = np.zeros(arr.shape, bool)
    for dim in range(arr.ndim):
        mask[tuple(slice(0, num) if idx == dim else slice(None) for idx in range(arr.ndim))] = True  
        mask[tuple(slice(-num, None) if idx == dim else slice(None) for idx in range(arr.ndim))] = True  
    return mask
```

As already said this creates and returns a `mask` where the borders are masked (`True`):

```
>>> mask_borders(np.ones((5,5)))
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

>>> # Besides supporting arbitary dimensional input it can mask multiple border rows/cols
>>> mask_borders(np.ones((5,5)), 2)
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

To get the "border" values this needs to be applied with [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) to your array:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[4,5,6,7], [2,2,6,3], [4,4,9,4], [8,1,6,1]])

>>> arr[mask_borders(arr)]
array([4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 4, 8, 1, 6, 1])
```

Comment: Nice! I had a similar idea thought in a vectorized way.

Comment: @Divakar I had some trouble vectorizing it if the shape is not identical in all dimensions. I will definitly check your answer!

Comment: Yeah, so if the shape of `a` is `(m,n)`, my solution would change to : `r1 = np.minimum(np.arange(n)[::-1], np.arange(n))` and similarly for `r2` using `m` and finally the boolean mask with `np.minimum(r2[:,None],r1)` if I got those dims correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check this complete solution solution. [This is the source](https://gist.github.com/blaylockbk/a70537b41050d1d761ab6c5ab6e4bd43)

```
def border(array, corner=0, direction='cw'):
"""
Extract the values arround the border of a 2d array.

Default settings start from top left corner and move clockwise. 
Corners are only used once.

Parameters
----------
array : array_like
    A 2d array
corner : {0, 1, 2, 3}
    Specify the corner to start at.
    0 - start at top left corner (default)
    1 - start at top right corner
    2 - start at bottom right corner
    3 - start at bottom left corner
direction : {'cw', 'ccw'}
    Specify the direction to walk around the array
    cw  - clockwise (default)
    ccw - counter-clockwise

Returns
-------
border : ndarray
    Values around the border of `array`.

Examples
--------
>>> x, y = np.meshgrid(range(1,6), range(5))
>>> array=x*y
>>> array[0,0]=999
array([[999,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
       [  2,   4,   6,   8,  10],
       [  3,   6,   9,  12,  15],
       [  4,   8,  12,  16,  20]])
>>> border(array)
array([999,   0,   0,   0,   0,   5,  10,  15,  20,  16,  12,   8,   4,
         3,   2,   1, 999])
>> border(array, corner=2)
array([ 20,  16,  12,   8,   4,   3,   2,   1, 999,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         5,  10,  15,  20])
>>> border(array, direction='ccw')
array([999,   1,   2,   3,   4,   8,  12,  16,  20,  15,  10,   5,   0,
         0,   0,   0, 999])
>>> border(array, corner=2, direction='ccw')
array([ 20,  15,  10,   5,   0,   0,   0,   0, 999,   1,   2,   3,   4,
         8,  12,  16,  20])
"""
if corner > 0:
    # Rotate the array so we start on a different corner
    array = np.rot90(array, k=corner)
if direction is 'ccw':
    # Transpose the array so we march around counter-clockwise
    array = array.T

border = []
border += list(array[0, :-1])    # Top row (left to right), not the last element.
border +=list(array[:-1, -1])    # Right column (top to bottom), not the last element.
border +=list(array[-1, :0:-1])  # Bottom row (right to left), not the last element.
border +=list(array[::-1, 0])    # Left column (bottom to top), all elements element.
# NOTE: in that last statement, we include the last element to close the path.

return np.array(border)
```