# Check if all sides of a multidimensional numpy array are arrays of zeros

Tags: python, numpy

An n-dimensional array has 2n sides (a 1-dimensional array has 2 endpoints; a 2-dimensional array has 4 sides or edges; a 3-dimensional array has 6 2-dimensional faces; a 4-dimensional array has 8 sides; etc.). This is analogous to what happens with abstract n-dimensional cubes.

I want to check if all sides of an n-dimensional array are composed by only zeros. Here are three examples of arrays whose sides are composed by zeros:

```
# 1D
np.array([0,1,2,3,0])
# 2D
np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 2, 3, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0]])
# 3D
np.array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0]],
          [[0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 2, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0]],
          [[0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

How can I check if all sides of a multidimensional numpy array are arrays of zeros? For example, with a simple 2-dimensional array I can do this:

```
x = np.random.rand(5, 5)
assert np.sum(x[0:,  0]) == 0
assert np.sum(x[0,  0:]) == 0
assert np.sum(x[0:, -1]) == 0
assert np.sum(x[-1, 0:]) == 0
```

While this approach works for 2D cases, it does not generalize to higher dimensions. I wonder if there is some clever numpy trick I can use here to make it efficient and also more maintainable.

Comment: Wouldn't `np.all (x[:,  0] == 0)` be safer than the sum? The sum test is correct only if all number are positive.

Comment: Related: [How to get all array edges?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41200719/7851470)

Comment: @Demi-Lume Makes sense. In my case, everything will be >=0 but your comment is appreciated :)

Comment: In a 3D case, do you mean faces (there are six of them) or edges (there are 12 of them) of the cube?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Yeah, 6 faces. but my issue is that it can go higher dimension than 3.

Comment: Yes I understand, just wanted to clarify your question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
assert(all(np.all(np.take(x, index, axis=axis) == 0)
           for axis in range(x.ndim)
           for index in (0, -1)))
```

[`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) does the same thing as "fancy" indexing.

Comment: This is awesome. I was not sure how I can loop over the axes indices and switch between 0 and -1. Did not know about `np.take`

Comment: @Luca: The documentation doesn't make it clear, but `numpy.take` makes a copy. This may cause it to perform worse than code based on a view. (Timing would be necessary to be sure - NumPy view efficiency is sometimes weird.)

Comment: Also, the use of a list comprehension prevents `all` from short-circuiting. You could remove the brackets to use a generator expression, allowing `all` to return as soon as a single `numpy.all` call returns `False`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica True!!

Answer (score 5):

Here's an answer that actually examines the parts of the array you're interested in, and doesn't waste time constructing a mask the size of the whole array. There's a Python-level loop, but it's short, with iterations proportional to the number of dimensions instead of the array's size.

```
def all_borders_zero(array):
    if not array.ndim:
        raise ValueError("0-dimensional arrays not supported")
    for dim in range(array.ndim):
        view = numpy.moveaxis(array, dim, 0)
        if not (view[0] == 0).all():
            return False
        if not (view[-1] == 0).all():
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Are there any circumstances where `not (view[0] == 0).all()` isn't equivalent to `view[0].any()`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer: I suppose `view[0].any()` would work too. I'm not entirely sure of the efficiency implications of the casting and buffering involved in the two options - `view[0].any()` could theoretically be implemented faster, but I've seen weird results before, and I don't fully understand the buffering involved.

Comment: I suppose `view[0].view(bool).any()` would be the high-speed solution.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: [`argmax` might actually beat `any` over the boolean view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771554/why-numpy-any-has-no-short-circuit-mechanism/45774536#45774536). This stuff gets weird.

Comment: (Also, whether `argmax` or `any`, using a boolean view means handling negative zero as unequal to regular zero.)

Comment: Actually, wait - `view(bool)` isn't safe, because we can't guarantee that arbitrary nonzero bit patterns are treated as equivalent to the bit pattern normally used for a true boolean.

Comment: It's easy to check and it works as expected. But you are still right in that this probably is an implementation detail, not a spec.

Answer (score 2):

I reshaped the array and then iterated through it.  Unfortunately, my answer assumes you have at least three dimensions and will error out for normal matrices, you would have to add a special clause for 1 & 2 dimensional shaped arrays.  In addition, this will be slow so there are likely better solutions.

```
x = np.array(
        [
            [
                [0 , 1, 1, 0],
                [0 , 2, 3, 0],
                [0 , 4, 5, 0]
            ],
            [
                [0 , 6, 7, 0],
                [0 , 7, 8, 0],
                [0 , 9, 5, 0]
            ]
        ])

xx = np.array(
        [
            [
                [0 , 0, 0, 0],
                [0 , 2, 3, 0],
                [0 , 0, 0, 0]
            ],
            [
                [0 , 0, 0, 0],
                [0 , 7, 8, 0],
                [0 , 0, 0, 0]
            ]
        ])

def check_edges(x):

    idx = x.shape
    chunk = np.prod(idx[:-2])
    x = x.reshape((chunk*idx[-2], idx[-1]))
    for block in range(chunk):
        z = x[block*idx[-2]:(block+1)*idx[-2], :]
        if not np.all(z[:, 0] == 0):
            return False
        if not np.all(z[:, -1] == 0):
            return False
        if not np.all(z[0, :] == 0):
            return False
        if not np.all(z[-1, :] == 0):
            return False

    return True
```

Which will produce

```
>>> False
>>> True
```

Basically I stack all the dimensions on top of each other and then look through them to check their edges.

Comment: This examines the wrong parts of the array. For a 3-dimensional array, we want to examine the faces of the whole array, not the edges of each 2-dimensional subarray.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.  I misunderstood

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) and boolean masking to get the job done:

```py
def get_borders(arr):
    s=tuple(slice(1,i-1) for i in a.shape)
    mask = np.ones(arr.shape, dtype=bool)
    mask[s] = False
    return(arr[mask])
```

This function first shapes the "core" of the array into the tuple `s`, and then builds a mask that shows `True` only for the bordering points. Boolean indexing then delivers the border points.

Working example:

```py
a = np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))

print(a)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

borders = get_borders(a)
print(borders)
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  7,  8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
```

Then, `np.all(borders==0)` will give you the desired information.

---

**Note:** this breaks for one-dimensional arrays, though I consider those an edge case. You're probably better off just checking the two points in question there

Comment: This takes time proportional to the total number of elements in the array, instead of just the border. Also, one-dimensional arrays are not an irrelevant edge case.

Comment: Also, `np.arange(15)` doesn't include 15.

Comment: I agree that "irrelevant" is a strong wording, though I feel you're better off just checking the two concerning points for a 1d array. The 15 is a typo, good catch

Answer (score 1):

maybe the ellipsis operator is what you are looking for, which will work for many dimensions:

```
import numpy as np

# data
x = np.random.rand(2, 5, 5)
x[..., 0:, 0] = 0
x[..., 0, 0:] = 0
x[..., 0:, -1] = 0
x[..., -1, 0:] = 0

test = np.all(
    [
        np.all(x[..., 0:, 0] == 0),
        np.all(x[..., 0, 0:] == 0),
        np.all(x[..., 0:, -1] == 0),
        np.all(x[..., -1, 0:] == 0),
    ]
)

print(test)
```

Comment: This will not colour all the faces. For example, try it with a (4, 4, 4) cube.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by colouring faces, but it does work if you make x (4, 4, 4)